# How can I make a data logging multimeter?(harvesting energy from human motion)

Tags: electronics

I’m an industrial design major working on a studio project that involves electronics that are kind of out of my league. I have a few low power generators like piezos, thermoelectric (peltier) tiles etc... In order to progress with my project I need a way to measure the output of each one individually when harvesting human motion. As far as I know, I need a multimeter to hook up directly to these devices, and then I think there may be a way to record the results with an arduino. My question is more about specifically how to do this, or even if this is a feasible plan. Are there any plans for this sort of thing already out there? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If these electronics are out of your league, how would adding more electronics (Arduino) aid on achieving your goal?

Comment: I think using a regular multimeter (potentially with logging capacity) will be easier than making such a thing yourself...

Comment: I'd suggest starting with an oscilloscope. Use that to examine the patterns of signals you're getting from each sensor, and then you might need help from somebody with a decent understanding of analog circuit design to design circuits to measure the inputs from the various sensors.

Comment: you could use an INA219 to measure voltage with an ardunio, like a DMM but for voltage and current only.